# I am trying to combine Spring WebMVC and Apache CXF but the service can't be found. Why?

Tags: spring-mvc, cxf

I am trying to setup a project with spring-WebMVC and Apache CXF but always if I try to invoke a web service, a message appears which tells me: "No service was found."

In the apache tomcat log, there is a warning:

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController invoke
WARNING: Can't find the request for 
http://localhost:8080/HelloWebService/rs/user-service/users's Observer
```

Here are the project configurations:

1. web.xml:

   ```
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <display-name>RESTful service</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>cxf.rest.root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
   ```
2. mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

   ```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.home.playground" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
   ```
3. appContext.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="false">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="userService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="userService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="userService" class="org.home.playground.services.UserService"/>

    </beans>
   ```

I am using this index.jsp as first page of the webapp. The index.jsp contains following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>CXF RESTful services and Spring-WebMVC Test page</h2>
    <a href="rs/user-service/users">get all users</a>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

The restful web service looks like that:

```
package org.home.playground.interfaces;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.home.playground.apputils.UserCollection;
import org.home.playground.models.User;

@Path("/user-service/")
@Produces("application/xml")
public interface IUserService {

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public UserCollection getUsers();

    @GET
    @Path("/user/{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathParam("id") Integer id);

    @GET
    @Path("/users/bad")
    public Response getBadRequest();

    @POST
    @Path("/new")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void newUser(
            @FormParam("id") Integer id,
            @FormParam("name") String name,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse
    ) throws IOException;


}
```

My Spring-webMVC controller looks like that:

```
package org.home.playground.web.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    protected ModelAndView showHelloWorldView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");

        return model;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/postUser")
    protected ModelAndView postUserForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("postUser");

        return model;
    }
}
```

Do you know why I can't invoke the web service? Is it possible to combine Spring-WebMVC with Apache CXF or aren't these frameworks compatible in one project?
If you need some more information, just tell me and I will provide them.
Your help is highly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a new application? Why bother with old XML configs, you can create an XML free configuration.

Comment: I am old school and I like my configurations in xml. Nevertheless this isn't  the topic of my main problem... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have split up the project in 2 projects.
The one project contains the web service stuff and the other one the Spring WebMVC stuff. I am not sure if there is another possibility to solve this problem but it works this way.